# Python HTTPServer responding to curl but not to Postman GET request

Tags: python-3.x, get, postman, httpserver

Consider a simple server in Python3 with the module `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import bson.json_util

class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        print("/n=================================")
        json_string = '{"hello":"world"}'
        self.wfile.write(json_string.encode())
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
    server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 3030), GetHandler)
    print ('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
    server.serve_forever()
```

This is responding correctly with `curl` from the Terminal:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3030/
```

However when trying to send a request from Postman it is not responding. I tried the URL `localhost:3030/`, `http://localhost:3030/` and also with the  loopback address.

Why is that?

Comment: I think curl and postman have a different user agent, which might cause differences in the way the server responds. Check also that Postman sends a GET and not a POST.

Comment: you can see actual command and body used by postman for executing the request. please post that here.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Can you capture both requests with something like fiddler and see what the difference is?

Comment: No need to use fiddler. [Postman has a built in console which displays the details of every request.](https://blog.getpostman.com/2016/08/26/the-postman-console/)

Comment: Thank you all. The problem actually was specifying the content-type. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all the examples I have seen it was not specifying the content type so I did the same way and seeing that `curl` worked I did not worry too much.

However content type should be specified: adding these lines before `self.wfile.write(...)`solves the problem:

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
self.end_headers()
```

Please note that actually `self.send_response(200)` has been moved, not added.